# how i can read from excel file in android?

Tags: java, android

i  wanna make my App read from excel file , i try Buffer Reader but doesn't work 
i want to know what exactly should i do at first also what the syntax for file 
i try this also doesn't work

```
File data = new File(getFilesDir(),"dat.csv");
        Scanner sc=null;
        try {
            sc = new Scanner(data);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        int i = 0;
        while (sc.hasNext()) {
            String Lines = sc.nextLine();
            //System.out.println(Lines);
            i++;
```

Comment: any error or exception?

Comment: Excel files are very hard to read. You are referring to a CSV file, which is plain text. Please rename the title.